# Mac OS X - Terminal window shows up but closes immediately

Tags: macos, mac

I'm using Mac OS X Lion 10.7. I open Terminal and its window shows up but immediately close and its icon remains in the dock. It's working fine a moment ago. I don't know what i have messed. I looked at the log file in the Console application and see "login: USER_PROCESS 172 ttys000"

Comment: Does this happen if you create a new user and then use that?

Answer (score 4):

I recently had this issue because I uninstalled the version of bash installed by macports (`/opt/local/bin/bash`) not realizing it was my default shell. The solution was to change my default shell back to `/bin/bash` via the advanced user options in the Users & Groups System Preferences. (See [@sdmeyers' comment on @Pyrolistical's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88794/mac-os-x-terminal-window-shows-up-but-closes-immediately#comment104125_88796) for instructions.)

Comment: That's the shit !

Answer (score 3):

This looks as if there is an issue with one of the configuration files for your shell. To fix do

1. With Terminal still running, use <kbd>Shift-Cmd-N</kbd> to run `zsh`
2. In `zsh` run `ls -l .bashrc .profile` and rename all files you found (`mv .bashrc .bashrc.save`, `mv .profile .profile.save`)
3. With the window still open, type <kbd>Cmd-T</kbd> to open a new tab running `bash`.
4. Assuming this worked, review `.bashrc.save`/`.profile.save` (and anything called from there) for errors. You can also rename them back and run `login` in the running shell which may show some errors from executing the scripts and give you some hints on where to look for problems.
5. In case running `bash` in step 3 didn't work (tab closed again) you may also have to rename `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc` with `sudo mv /etc/profile /etc/profile.save; sudo mv /etc/bashrc /etc/bashrc.save`

Answer (score 1):

Try to hide the current `~/.bash_profile` from your shell.
Just rename it to `~/.bash_profile_bkp` and see if something changes.

Answer (score 0):

What shell are you using?  Try flipping the default one.  I found a bad .profile configuration crashed bash, and temporarily switching to another shell to edit the .profile fixed my issue.

Comment: Can you describe how the default shell can be changed?

Comment: In the User & Groups System Preference, Right(Control)+Click on the user whose shell you want to change. This should present an "Advanced options..." option. Select it and it will bring up a pane allowing you to select a number of options including the Login shell. BTW, this option is really the only option I'd suggest ever changing.